# Empty UITableView still shows empty cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, calendar

I am making a Calendar app and I am showing the events from the Calendar in a `UITableView`.
I am using a `tableFooterView` to hide separator lines in a `UITableView` when the table is empty. I do this with the following code:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
UILabel *footerTableViewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
footerTableViewLabel.text = @"No items.";
[self.tableView.tableFooterView addSubview:footerTableViewLabel];
```

If there are elements in the table, I hide this view, and if not I show it. This works fine if the calendar is initially empty. However, if I delete an event from Calendar.app while my app is still running in the background, when I go back to the app, all I see is a bunch of empty cells and separator, and no label saying "No items".

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I show/hide the footer view using:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView.hidden = NO/YES;
```

As far as events are considered, I do not offer the possibility to delete them directly from my app, I just detect when they are deleted from Calendar.app. Unfortunately, I cannot show the code doing this detection since it is part of a private library, however, this works fine, i.e. I jump to right parts of code when the event is deleted.

Comment: Show us code for showing/hiding footer and deleting event.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this un your code to hide separators: `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

Comment: Yes, but I would still like to show my footerView and the label saying there are no items, instead of a completely white view.

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;` to hide the separator lines. If you want the active tableview cells to have separators, you can always add a border to the bottom of each cell manually using a function like this:

```
- (void)addBottomBorderWithColor:(UIColor *)color andHeight:(CGFloat) borderHeight
{
    CALayer *borderBottom = [CALayer layer];
    borderBottom.backgroundColor = color.CGColor;
    borderBottom.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width, borderHeight);
    [self.layer addSublayer:borderBottom];
}
```

** EDIT**
If you want to add a view that indicates 'no data', try adding this as a view underneath the tableview, then just set the tableview to hidden if there is no data present.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally managed to figure this out. There were to issues:

1. For some reason (maybe when I do `[self.tableView reloadData]`), `self.tableView.tableFooterView` would become nil and that's why I could see empty cells. Reassigning the view to it fixed this issue.
2. I had to update the view constraints for the footer view and the label it contains.